# Stubbing a method that takes Class<T> as parameter with Mockito

Tags: java, class, generics, mocking, mockito

There is a generic method that takes a class as parameter and I have problems stubbing it with Mockito. The method looks like this:

```
public <U extends Enum<U> & Error, T extends ServiceResponse<U>> T validate(
    Object target, Validator validator, Class<T> responseClass,
    Class<U> errorEnum);
```

It's god awful, at least to me... I could imagine living without it, but the rest of the code base happily uses it...

I was going to, in my unit test, stub this method to return a new empty object. But how do I do this with mockito? I tried:

```
when(serviceValidatorStub.validate(
    any(), 
    isA(UserCommentRequestValidator.class), 
    UserCommentResponse.class, 
    UserCommentError.class)
).thenReturn(new UserCommentResponse());
```

but since I am mixing and matching matchers and raw values, I get "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers!"

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but eq() or same() is not working for me. Code is written in Kotlin.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The problem is, you cannot mix argument matchers and real arguments in a mocked call. So, rather do this:

```
when(serviceValidatorStub.validate(
    any(),
    isA(UserCommentRequestValidator.class),
    eq(UserCommentResponse.class),
    eq(UserCommentError.class))
).thenReturn(new UserCommentResponse());
```

Notice the use of the `eq()` argument matcher for matching equality.

see: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#eq(T)

Also, you could use the `same()` argument matcher for `Class<?>` types - this matches same identity, like the `==` Java operator.

Comment: Indeed. But I wonder if Mockito could be improved to allow users to "mix argument matchers and real arguments"; if Unitils Mock could do it, then it should be technically possible.

Comment: That `eq(UserCommentError.class)` is cool and clear in the stub.

Answer (score 3):

Just in order to complete on the same thread, if someone want to stubb a method that takes a Class as argument, but don't care of the type, or need many type to be stubbed the same way, here is another solution:

```
private class AnyClassMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<Class<?>> {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(final Object argument) {
        // We always return true, because we want to acknowledge all class types
        return true;
    }

}

private Class<?> anyClass() {
    return Mockito.argThat(new AnyClassMatcher());
}
```

and then call

```
Mockito.when(mock.doIt(this.anyClass())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Comment: This is a very good answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Nice one @Ash. I used your generic class matcher to prepare below.
This can be used if we want to prepare mock of a specific Type.(not instance)

```
private Class<StreamSource> streamSourceClass() {
    return Mockito.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Class<StreamSource>>() {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(Mockito.anyString(), 
            **streamSourceClass(),**
            Mockito.anyObject));
```