# How to mock a method which takes Class as parameter

Tags: junit

I can mock a method like printMyValue(String value);
like
when(myClass.printMyValue(anyString())then return "Some value";

But how can i mock printMyValue(MyClass value);

Comment: Try the answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462096/stubbing-a-method-that-takes-classt-as-parameter-with-mockito

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "any" method. You just can't statically import it. Your code will look something like this:

```
package jtsandbox;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;




/**
 * Explains mocking question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392623/how-to-mock-a-method-which-takes-class-as-parameter/29393040#29393040 
 * @author Jason W. Thompson (https://plus.google.com/+JasonWThompson_SoftwareDeveloper)
 */
public class TestStuff
{
    /**
     * Tests mocking
     * @throws Exception An exception is not expected to be thrown
     */
    @Test
    public void testmethod() throws Exception
    {
        // Given
        final Foo mockFoo = mock(Foo.class);
        when(mockFoo.printMyValue(Mockito.<Class<?>>any())).thenReturn("Hi!");

        // When
        final String answer = mockFoo.printMyValue(String.class);

        // Then
        assertThat(answer, is("Hi!"));
    }



    public interface Foo
    {
        public String printMyValue(Class<?> clazz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Mockito's `any` matcher:

```
when(myClass.printMyValue(any(MyClass.class)).thenReturn("Some value");
```