# JUnit: Intercepting a method call and then invoking with different params

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock

I am working on junit and using PowerMockRunner to mock static methods.

I am aware that static methods can be mocked using `when(...).thenReturn(...)`

I need to mock a certain method that takes four arguments:

```
public static void addInputPath(String, Boolean, Integer, Double)
```

I need the third parameter(Integer) in any call to this method to be replaced by, say `10`. All other parameters should just be passed as is.

In other words, I need to do something like this:

```
when(addInputPath(str, bool, intgr, dbl)).thenReturn(addInputPath(str, bool, 10, dbl));
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This question is answered in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462096/stubbing-a-method-that-takes-classt-as-parameter-with-mockito

Comment: I don't believe that you can replace an argument, what you can do is giving the returned value of your method for given set arguments

Comment: @kolakao Not sure if that's what I want. Simplified my question.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Can you refer me to an example?

Comment: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#mocking-static-method

Comment: Thanks @NicolasFilotto But that's not actually my requirement :( I need the method to still be called and executed, not just mocked.

Comment: What is the point of this requirement?! You are **mocking** a method. You create a **test double** that only exists so that the code calling it ... can do so. There is no point in making sure that your mock is always called with "10"? Or are you asking how you can **verify** that the third parameter is always 10?

Comment: Okay, I probably wasn't clear enough. Let's say I have a method `xyz()` that is being tested. Inside this method, there's a call to the static method in question - `addInputPath(str, bool, intgr, dbl)`. Now whenever such a call is encountered, I want it to be replaced by `addInputPath(str, bool, 10, dbl)`. I.e. I want something like `when(addInputPath(str, bool, intgr, dbl)).thenReturn(addInputPath(str, bool, 10, dbl))`. Hope I was able to clearly phrase my question this time.

Comment: addInputPath(...) is a 3rd party library method. It's not much in my scope to explain why it has 4 parameters or what is the need for me to do what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when I get your requirements right, what you actually want to do is to **intercept** the call to addInputPath() and invoke it with a different parameter?

If so: I am not sure if this can be done with any mocking framework (and I doubt that it is possible). Mocking frameworks are about **mocking** calls; not about instrumenting/intercepting calls.

Coming back to your problem, this is a nice example why **static** calls far too often cause problems. Thus, the best solution in my eyes would be to change your method xyz() to avoid that thing calling addInputPath() directly. Like this:

```
interface InputPathAdder {
   void addInputPath(str, ... );
}

class ForwardingInputPathAdder implements InputPathAdder {
   // implements the method by calling the static method
```

and all of a sudden, you can also do:

```
class ForwardingInputPathAdderWithFixedIntegerParm implements InputPathAdder {
   // implements the method by calling the static method, but using 10 always
```

( obviously, naming could be improved here )

And now: you use dependency injection to give your "class under test" some Object implementing InputPathAdder. This could be either one that is completely mocked for testing; or it could be one that just does forwarding (in your production environment; or it could be the one that fixes the 3rd parameter). And no need for mocking for your "intercept" situation.